# Why does (ps -f) create no subshell but a separate process?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I need some help because I don't get something. From what I read from Internet, a subshell is created when we execute a shell script or if we run command in brackets: `( )`

I tried to test this with a script which contains only the following command:

```
ps -f
```

When I run it I see the following result:

```
ID      PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD 
me     2213  2160  0 08:53 pts/14   00:00:00 bash 
me     3832  2213  0 18:41 pts/14   00:00:00 bash 
me     3833  3832  0 18:41 pts/14   00:00:00 ps -f
```

Which is good, because I see that my bash process has spawned another bash process for my script.

But when I do:

```
( ps -f )
```

it produces:

```
UID     PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD 
me     2213  2160  0 08:53 pts/14   00:00:00 bash 
me     3840  2213  0 18:46 pts/14   00:00:00 ps -f
```

So if brackets spawn a subshell why it is not shown in the processes? And why does `ps -f` is counted as another process? Does every command run as a separate process?

Comment: Use `ps -ef` to show all processes.

Comment: Who in their right mind would want to close this as off-topic? The increasing number of trolls on SO is worrying me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you've caught `bash` in a little bit of an optimization.  if a subshell contains only a single command, why really make it a subshell?

```
$ ( ps -f )
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
jovalko  29393 24133  0 12:05 pts/10   00:00:00 bash
jovalko  29555 29393  0 12:07 pts/10   00:00:00 ps -f
```

However, add a second command, say `:` (the bash null command, which does nothing) and this is the result:

```
$ ( ps -f ; : )
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
jovalko  29393 24133  0 12:05 pts/10   00:00:00 bash
jovalko  29565 29393  0 12:08 pts/10   00:00:00 bash
jovalko  29566 29565  0 12:08 pts/10   00:00:00 ps -f
```

One of the main reasons to use a subshell is that you can perform operations like I/O redirection on a group of commands instead a single command, but if your subshell contains only a single command there's not much reason to really fork a new bash process first.

As to `ps` counting as a process, it varies. Many commands you use like `ls`, `grep`, `awk` are all external programs. But, there are builtins like `cd`, `kill`, too.

You can determine which a command is in `bash` using the `type` command:

```
$ type ps
ps is hashed (/bin/ps)
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
```

Answer (score 2):

The main part of the question is:

> Does every command run as a separate process?

YES!. Every command what isn't built-in into bash (like `declare` and such), runs as separate process. How it is works?

When you type `ps` and press enter, the bash analyze what you typed, do usual things as globbing, variable expansionas and such, and finally when it is an external command

- the bash `forks` itself.

The *forking* mean, than immediatelly after the *fork,* you will have *two* **identical** `bash` processes (each one with different process ID (PID)) - called as "parent" and "child", and the only difference between those two running `bash` programs is, than the "parent" gets (return value from the `fork`) the PID of the child but the child don't know the PID of the parent. (fork for the child returns 0).

- after the fork, (bash is written this way) - the child *replaces itself* with the new program image (such: `ps`) - using the `exec` call.
- after this, the child bash of course doesn't exist anymore, and running only the newly executed command - e.g. the `ps`.

Of course, when the bash going to fork itself, do many other things, like I/O redirections, opens-closes filehandles, changes signal handling for the child and many-many other things.

Comment: Thank you! You really clarified what I asked.

Comment: Well, I have another question. If every external command is executed using fork, and shell scripts are counted like external commands, why when we use brackets ( ) all variables are visible for the subshell, but when we run shell scripts only the EXPORTED variables are visible for the script?

Comment: @CuriousGuy remember the `fork`? _two_ **identical** processes. **both** are `bash`. In the case of "scripts", executed the `exec` part to, (based on shebang) - so the child bash replace itself with an new command (usually /bin/bash too, but the newly executed one) - in the case of brackets, **the forked child** (bash too, but the old one) doing the work (it is `forked` is an new - but it is identical as parent - so knows everything).

Comment: Yes, I just got to this conclusion after a few minutes of thinking. Thank you for confirming it :)